# How to install pyodide package on vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, data-science, data-analysis, pyodide

I want to use the pyodide package on a data analysis project on vs code but i can't install this packcage , I need help please

```
I tried to run pip install pyodide but i have this problem :
```

Collecting pyodide
Using cached pyodide-0.0.2.tar.gz (19 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\Mouad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hytn_jkn\pyodide_d2f2163c84794780a8a92f7a373c9c76\setup.py", line 7, in 
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Pyodide is a Python distribution that runs in the browser or Node.js. It cannot be installed from PyPi.
See https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide for how to use Pyodide.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Pyodide is a JavaScript package that is loaded in the web browser. It is not installed via pip.

Comment: and what should I do to use this package on my project ?

Comment: Pyodide has documentation on how to install the package.

Comment: Read [this docs](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-custom-python-code.html) for more details.

Comment: There was a highly experimental extension [vscode-pyodide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joyceerhl.vscode-pyodide), see [here](https://twitter.com/simonw/status/1450875176447475720). However, things are changing rapidly in the WASM/pyodide arena and it looks like left un-updated for now until the dust settles.